# The Shielding of valence p Electrons of Bromine Atoms

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

So I was studying Slater's Rule and this question came up on [libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Mount_Royal_University/Chem_1201/Unit_2._Periodic_Properties_of_the_Elements/2.06%3A_Slater%27s_Rules#:%7E:text=What%20is%20the%20shielding%20constant%20experienced%20by%20a%20valence%20p%2Delectron%20in%20the%20bromine%20atom%3F)
The electronic configuration of Br would be $1s^22s^22p^63s^23p^64s^23d^{10}4p^5$

So according to my calculations, the Screening constant would be $2+8+(8 \times 0.85)+10+(\underline6 \times 0.35) = 28.9$ but the answer given is $2+8+(8 \times 0.85)+10+( \underline4 \times 0.35) = 28.2$

Is the answer given in libretexts wrong?

Comment: I dont think my answer is wrong
An electron in the valence p subshell has 4 p-neighbours and 2 s-neighbours so it should be (4+2)*(0.35) = 6*0.35 as I understand the slater's rules

Comment: You seem right. // alternative [Libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/General_Chemistry_Supplement_(Eames)/Periodic_Trends/Slater%27s_Rules_for_Effective_Nuclear_Charge) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation :)

Comment: In my understanding, they confused the groups of orbitals of the same kind like np versus the Slater rule specific groups, merging ns and np orbitals.